# How to set up crontab in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bash, cron, rsync

I have written several backup tasks in crontab and I use rsync to do the backup.

One of the backup tasks is as follows：

```
30 1 * * 6 root rsync -avz super@192.168.0.5::codelab /backup/gitlab --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

The purpose is to back up at 1.30 every Saturday。

But this task was not executed and I would like to know why it was not executed?

When I run this line of command from the command line:

```
sudo rsync -avz super@192.168.0.5::codelab /backup/gitlab --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

It is executed successfully.

Comment: Where did you place the cron task? in /etc/crontab or via crontab -e?

Comment: @steeldriver , I use crontab -e

Comment: In that case, the syntax is wrong: user crontabs don't have the extra user field - drop the `root` and use root's crontab instead i.e. `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: @steeldriver ， You mean first I use this command:

sudo crontab -e

Then I add a task schedule: 

30 1 * * 6 rsync -avz super@192.168.0.5::codelab /backup/gitlab --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.secrets

Comment: @steeldriver, I will try your method. Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes that should work - barring issues with the `rsync` command itself (remember that cron jobs run in a very restricted environment, not at all like that of your interactive shell). For that reason, you might want to add `>path/to/logfile 2>&1` to capture any potential informational or error messages to a log file.